# Querying with Large FeatureCollection in Google Earth Engine using Python?

Tags: shapefile, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, google-earth-api

I am trying to process a Tanzania shapefile downloaded from [GADM Global Administrative Areas](http://www.gadm.org/country).

```
    # im -> {Image} ee.Image({...})
    # self.geom_coll -> {FeatureCollection} ee.FeatureCollection({...}). containing 
    # 3000 features.
    # spacereducer() -> ee.Reducer.mean
    # self.scale -> 10 #Changing this value to small number gives error

    feats = im.reduceRegions(self.geom_coll, spacereducer(), self.scale)
    flist = getInfo_werrorcontrol(feats,
                          self.errorcheck)['features']
```

.

```
def getInfo_werrorcontrol(featureCollection, errorcontrolon=True):
    """
    Wrapper to add error control to GEE evaluations.

    For large computations GEE sometimes times out and needs to be
    restarted. This does so in a controlled manner with out 
    interrrupting the program flow.
    """
    if errorcontrolon:
        i=0
        while True:
            try:
                with timeout.timeout(10*60):
                    return featureCollection.getInfo() # In this line I am getting exception.
            except NameError:
                exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
                lines = traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
                print ''.join('!! ' + line for line in lines)
                i+=1
                print 'attempts: '+str(i)
                if i > 20:
                    raise ValueError('to many attempts') 
                elif i > 10:
                    print 'waiting 2 minutes'
                    time.sleep(60*2)
    else:
        return featureCollection.getInfo()
```

Exception:-
Changing **self.scale** to 10 gives me following error for line: **featureCollection.getInfo()**

> ee.ee_exception.EEException: Server returned HTTP code: 413

Changing **self.scale** to 1000 gives me following error:

> ee.ee_exception.EEException: Computation timed out

What is the correct way to process shapefile with the larger region?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error.. I tried with a fc with 2999 feats and Hansen Forest Change as Image, and worked with scale 10 and 1000.